# Creating a task as a bug in Phabricator

Tags: phabricator

I am new to phabricator.

I am trying to create a bug on Phabricator for a project.

All I am seeing is create a task. No sub category of that task that whether it is a bug/backlogItem etc.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Phabricator you don't have bugs as separate thing. All are tasks. You can think that bug are task with high priority.

Although you can add a custom field to indicate if they are bug, improvements or what you want. If you want to know more about custom fields, so you can add a field "type", see https://secure.phabricator.com/book/phabricator/article/custom_fields/.

Comment: Thanks Phoneix. I have created bugs by writing 'Bug:' as a prefix for the task

Answer (score 2):

You can now set task type while creating a task

[image]

Comment: From which version it have this new feature?

Comment: This is related to custom field that you have mentioned. I was unaware of the fact that this was a custom field which an admin in my company has added into phabricator.

Answer (score 1):

Adding custom fields can solve the problem. You can add bug as a custom field under type.
Also assign a key to the custom field
go to your

```
Maniphest Configuration
 maniphest.custom-field-definitions

 "key:hashtag": { "name": "Type", "type": "select", "options": { "key:task": "Task", "key:discussion": "Discussion", "key:bug": "Bug" },
```

this way you can also search all task, discussion or bugs in the search bar by just typing key:task or key:bug or key:discussion

Answer (score 0):

You can **tag** your tickets as Bugs.

In Phabricator terminology **Tags** are the same as **Projects**. These "Project Tags" can be assigned to any Maniphest Tickets.

In your case you could simply create a **new project** named "**Bug**" and select the Bug icon and red color for it. Then you can assign this Tag to any Ticket.

The Tag will look like this then:

[image]

Comment: try to highlight the keywords and be clear with the format it will help to reach out your answer for others  [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)